# Unable to view uploaded timeseries data in UI chart

Tags: databus

Running the Databus server from the command line I have successfully uploaded timeseries data via curl, and am able to query the same data with the api.  I'm unable to view any of the data in the table in the UI. After selecting "My Databus" -> Tables is says "You do not belong to any groups that have tables yet. Add some groups, then tables!!!".  Navigating to the Database and selecting the table -> chart no data comes back there either.

I have noticed that the query it issues is from a recent time range, while the data I loaded is for an earlier time period.  Is there a default way to show the most recent data available in a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your table type relational or stream?  If relational, what is the primary key?

If time series, this url will give you the last 10 values because of the parameter 10 and reverse=true.

http://[yourhost]/api/firstvaluesV1/10/rawdataV1/[yourtablename]?reverse=true

If relational table, you can retreive all values like so

http://[yourhost]/api/getdataV1/select+c+from+[yourtablename]+as+c

replace either urls [yourhost] and [yourtablename] values.

We do not use the tables page much.  It is better to click in the specific database as in My Databus -> Databases and then click on the database that has your table.  We are about to add a view data link in there showing most recent 1000 values or something like that.  There is already a view chart which shows most recent 2 hours(again, we want to change that to most recent 1000 data points instead as well).

Comment: The table type is stream.  Yes the query returns the last 10 values of the dataset.  Ok when going to My Databus -> Databases and selecting my database the view chart doesn't show any data.  Is this because the  time values are older than 2 hrs?  I guess I'm confused about how I can create a chart for my time range and put it on the dashboard.  Thanks!

Comment: yes, it only shows last 2 hours right now.  We want to change that to the last 1000 data points instead for every table using the firstvalues type url(putting 1000 instead of 10).  Let me have phil answer how to get it on the dashboard since he worked on that(we plan to improve that a lot as well)

Comment: edited my post since it stripped out the less than and greater than signs and replaced it with [ and ] which work

Comment: so I just found out we can't get the custom charts into the dashboard yet but in the MyDatabus->Charts wizard, at the end you can click chart only and that is the url you can put in an iframe of any web page of any website to create a dashboard until we remedy this.  to use MyDatabus->Charts, you will want to use the url http://[yourhost]/api/rawdataV1/[yourtablename]/[starttime]/[endtime] and specify time as the time column and value as the value column.  I just added a ticket so we support firstvalues as that is a 10 minute fix so we show the most recent 1000 values

Comment: sounds like we may have this done in two weeks as it was put into this iteration.

Comment: it sounds like we should have this in soon...maybe 2 weeks as it is scheduled for this iteration to fix.